# Error while installing SDK MainEngineThread is returning 1603

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk

I am using windows server 2012 where I am trying to install SDK but it is     resulting in error with code 2753.
    I tried it with uninstalling VC redistributables still the same error.

Log file:

```
Action start 17:00:47: InstallInitialize.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:246]: Doing action: RemoveExistingProducts
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:246]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:246]: Transforming table Upgrade.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Transforming table Upgrade.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Upgrade 3: -2147287038 
Action start 17:00:48: RemoveExistingProducts.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Doing action: ProcessComponents
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchCertificate 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: LUA patching is disabled: missing MsiPatchCertificate table
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Resolving source to launched-from source.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Setting launched-from source as last-used.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property.                 Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\'.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\'.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourcedirProduct property. Its value is '{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}'.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: SOURCEDIR ==> C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Source type from package 'Application Verifier x64 External Package-x64_en-us.msi': 2
Action start 17:00:48: ProcessComponents.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Source path resolution complete. Dumping Directory table...
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: TARGETDIR    , Object:     C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-    7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key:     AppVerifierWow64AutomationRoot   , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: AppVerifierWow64CommonRoot   , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  ,     ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: System64Folder   , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: AppVerifier64BitCommonRoot   , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: AppVerifier64BitExternalRoot , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: AppVerifierWow64ExternalRoot , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: ProgramFiles64Folder , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath:  , ShortSubPath: 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: AppVerifier64BitAutomationRoot   , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath: Application Verifier\    , ShortSubPath: wxgxaivq\
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: WindowsKitsParent    , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath: Windows Kits\    , ShortSubPath: mmcruuon\
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: KitsRoot , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath: Windows Kits\8.0\    , ShortSubPath: mmcruuon\8.0\
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Dir (source): Key: dirCatalogRepositoryDirectory    , Object: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7346C35D-942D-3CCE-94CB-7008BA8D63CB}v8.59.25584\Installers\    , LongSubPath: Windows Kits\8.0\Catalogs\   , ShortSubPath: mmcruuon\8.0\Catalogs\
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Transforming table Registry.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Transforming table Registry.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:262]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:293]: Note: 1: 2753 2:     fild1b19317a3c2a591398d1fb156586eaf 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:293]: Note: 1: 2753 2: fild1b19317a3c2a591398d1fb156586eaf 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:324]: Note: 1: 2753 2: fil1814968f6151f8832e52a7c1c78a465c 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:340]: Note: 1: 2753 2: fil1814968f6151f8832e52a7c1c78a465c 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Doing action: UnpublishFeatures
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 17:00:48: UnpublishFeatures.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Skipping action:     AVRFInstall_UnInstallwow64External (condition is false)
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Skipping action:     AVRFInstall_UnInstallx64External (condition is false)
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Doing action: RemoveRegistryValues
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Transforming table Registry.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Transforming table Registry.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:371]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Registry 3: -2147287038 
Action start 17:00:48: RemoveRegistryValues.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Doing action: RemoveFiles
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: RemoveFile 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: RemoveFile 
Action start 17:00:48: RemoveFiles.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Doing action: InstallFiles
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
Action start 17:00:48: InstallFiles.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchOldAssemblyFile 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiPatchOldAssemblyFile     4: SELECT `MsiPatchOldAssemblyFile`.`Assembly_` FROM `MsiPatchOldAssemblyFile` WHERE  `MsiPatchOldAssemblyFile`.`File_` = ? 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiSFCBypass 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiSFCBypass 4: SELECT     `File_` FROM `MsiSFCBypass` WHERE `File_` = ? 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 4:     SELECT `Header` FROM `MsiPatchHeaders` WHERE `StreamRef` = ? 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiPatchHeaders 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:386]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:402]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:402]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:402]: Transforming table Property.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:464]: Transforming table Property.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:480]: Doing action:     AVRFInstall_Installwow64External
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:480]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action ended 17:00:48: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:480]: Note: 1: 2753 2:     fila2b33566fbf0db8812283e5617d62006
```

Action start 17:00:48: AVRFInstall_Installwow64External.
    DEBUG: Error 2753:  The File 'fila2b33566fbf0db8812283e5617d62006' is not     marked for installation.
    MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: Product: Application Verifier x64 External     Package -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this     package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2753.     The arguments are: fila2b33566fbf0db8812283e5617d62006, ,

```
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\    Scripts 3: 2 
Action ended 17:00:48: AVRFInstall_Installwow64External. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\    Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: No System Restore sequence number for this     installation.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:496]: Unlocking Server
Action ended 17:00:48: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:511]: Product: Application Verifier x64 External     Package - Update 'Application Verifier x64 External Package Patch' could not be     installed. Error code 1603. Additional information is available in the log file     C:\Users\Deven\AppData\Local\Temp\standalonesdk\Windows Software Development Kit_20150204165641_6_package_ApplicationVerifierx64ExternalPackagex64_en_us.log.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:527]: Windows Installer installed an update. Product Name: Application Verifier x64 External Package. Product Version: 8.59.29722. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft. Update Name: Application Verifier x64 External Package Patch. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:527]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Application Verifier x64 External Package. Product Version: 8.59.29722. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft. Installation success or error status: 1603.

MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:527]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\52b18.msp
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:542]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:542]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\52b18.msp
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:542]: Unable to delete the file outside of the     engine. LastError = 2
MSI (s) (DC:30) [17:00:48:542]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: No System Restore sequence number for this     installation.
=== Logging stopped: 2/4/2015  17:00:48 ===
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown.     Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\    Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\    Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:542]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If     counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (DC:F0) [17:00:48:558]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (s) (DC:B0) [17:00:48:558]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
MSI (c) (B0:88) [17:00:48:558]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (B0:88) [17:00:48:558]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 2/4/2015  17:00:48 ===
```